# Grails : Two Reference of Primary key in another table

Tags: database, grails

I have following two tables:

**tbTeams:**

- id
- name

**tbMatches**

- id
- team1
- team2
- score1
- score2

What I want is , the team1 and team2 columns on tbMatches are both derived from id on tbTeams. Please let me know how can I achieve this relationship in grails.

PS: I am new to Grails and have less knowledge of database. Please ignore any kinds of errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class TbTeam{
    String name

    //Optional
    static mapping = {
        table 'TB_TEAM'
        id column: 'TB_TEAM_ID'
    }
}

class TbMatch{
    Integer score1
    Integer score2

    TbTeam team1
    TbTeam team2

    static mapping = {
        table 'TB_MATCH'
        id column: 'TB_MATCH_ID'

        team1 column: 'TEAM_1' //maps to the primary key of TbTeam
        team2 column: 'TEAM_2' //maps to the primary key of TbTeam
    }
}
```

[GORM documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html) is a bible for Grails newbies [I guess for everyone :)]. Go through it.